# MongoDB insert_many fails on collection with a unique index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert, unique-index

I am trying to do a bulk insert on a collection with a unique index in MongoDB (pymongo client). My intention is to allow for a bulk insert and update values where a record matches another record with the same unique index value.

I created the index on `test_collection` like so:

```
db.test_collection.create_index({'a': 1}, {'unique': True})
```

Even on the first attempt, my bulk insert query fails with an unhelpful error message:

```
$ db.test_collection.insert_many(records, ordered=False)

> batch op errors occurred
```

I looked through `mongodb.log` and there are no error messages. Thoughts?

Comment: You get the error because some documents were not inserted. Verify the other documents were inserted as expected, then ignore the error in your application if that is what you want to do.

Comment: See https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html for diagnostics.